# Appengine devserver running on 2 ports

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

Upgraded my OS to Sierria, and installed JDK8, maven 3.3.9 and tried to run maven, and it throws an error. Going through appengine docs, it mentions "You can use Java 7 or Java 8, but you must use Java 7 bytecode level". So tried installing JDK7, but didn't work too. Tried to run on other ports, but the same problem occured.

```
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.48:devserver (default-cli) < package @ mark <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.48:devserver (default-cli) @ mark ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Running Development Server
[INFO] 
[INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
[INFO] Running /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -XstartOnFirstThread -javaagent:/Users/Raghu/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.48/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.48/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/Raghu/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.48/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.48/lib/override/appengine-dev-jdk-overrides.jar -Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5 -classpath /Users/Raghu/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.48/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.48/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --allow_remote_shutdown -p 8080 /Users/Raghu/git/site/target/mark-6
[INFO] objc[4320]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java (0x100e654c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x100f2e4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 11:21:05 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
[INFO] INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value '/Users/Raghu/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.48/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.48/config/sdk/logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from '/Users/Raghu/git/site/target/mark-6/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 11:21:06 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
[INFO] INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:06 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
[INFO] INFO: jetty-6.1.x
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:07 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
[INFO] INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:8080
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:07 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService startHotDeployScanner
[INFO] INFO: Full scan of the web app in place every 5s.
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:07 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] INFO: Module instance gamma is running at http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:07 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:07 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
[INFO] INFO: jetty-6.1.x
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:08 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
[INFO] INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:52747
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:08 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService startHotDeployScanner
[INFO] INFO: Full scan of the web app in place every 5s.
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:08 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] INFO: Module instance gamma instance 0 is running at http://localhost:52747/
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 5:51:08 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:52747/_ah/admin
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 11:21:08 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
[INFO] INFO: Dev App Server is now running
[INFO] Apr 02, 2017 11:21:08 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.InstanceHelper sendStartRequest
[INFO] WARNING: Got exception while performing /_ah/start request on server: 0.gamma, java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time on it, I had figured out that the problem was that I was using a backend instance B1 in appengine-web.xml with basic scaling. Solved it by using a Frontend instance F1 with automatic scaling and everything started to work fine. Since it was running locally, I thought appengine-web.xml wouldn't be considered, my bad.

In appengine-web.xml:

```
<instance-class>F1</instance-class>
<automatic-scaling>
    <max-idle-instances>1</max-idle-instances>
    <min-pending-latency>automatic</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>10ms</max-pending-latency>
    <max-concurrent-requests>5</max-concurrent-requests>
</automatic-scaling>
```